# Making a method generic over Array1<T>

Tags: generics, rust, rust-ndarray

I have the following Trait implementation and would like to make `unit` generic over `Array1<T>`, but fail to find the right Trait bounds (especially that this somehow seems trivial to me, all T needs to support is basically basic arithmetic that output T for the function to work).

```
trait Unit {
    fn unit(&self) -> Array1<f32>;
}

impl Unit for Array1<f32> 
{
    fn unit(&self) -> Array1<f32> {
        self / (self * self).sum().sqrt()
    }
}
```

The compiler suggests adding `std::ops::Mul<Output = &ArrayBase<OwnedRepr<T>, Dim<[usize; 1]>>>`, but doing so keeps giving the same error over and over.

[PlayGround](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=6e1f600dff8cad41038941a19b5aab30)

Comment: Do you want to make `unit` generic or the entire trait?

Comment: @AlexeyRomanov The `unit` method over all Array1. Sorry if it was not clear.

Comment: But then do you still have `impl Unit for Array1<f32>`? What should `let x: Array1<f32> = ...; let y = x.unit::<i32>()` actually do and what do you expect the type of `y` to be?

Comment: @AlexeyRomanov I want to have `impl <T> Unit for Array1<T>` so I can calculate the unit vector regardless of the type (e.g. f32, f64, u16,...) as long as they are numeric-like without having to manually implement all those by myself. I'm not sure whether this would require changes in the Trait definition itself or not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I followed the compiler error messages and produced this generic code that compiles. I'm not familiar with `ndarray` so I don't know if this is actually correct.

```rust
use std::ops::Mul;
use num_traits::{Zero, real::Real};
use ndarray::prelude::*;

trait Unit {
    type Output;
    fn unit(&self) -> Array1<Self::Output>;
}

impl<T> Unit for Array1<T>
where
    for<'a> &'a Array1<T>: Mul<Output = Array1<T>>,
    T: Real + Clone + Zero + ndarray::ScalarOperand,
{
    type Output = T;
    fn unit(&self) -> Array1<T> {
        self / (self * self).sum().sqrt()
    }
}
```

Note that `Unit` now returns an associated type. If you want it to always return `f32` then you'll need to require that `T` can be converted to `f32` too.